# Background Color loads before Angular template

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ngcloak

Sometimes background color is loading before the template being loaded in AngularJS.
I want to get rid of this.

I have tried ng-cloak but this doesnt work.

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: template file:
<div class="bgColor"> Color </div>

css file:
.bgColor{
  background-color: green;
}

Comment: its a normal html and css but background color is applied before the text being loaded.